# How to identify wifi card in laptop

Tags: networking, wireless-router

I'm running a Dell and a Sony laptops with XP sp2 and using a toshiba Windows 7 as wifi network host. I had been using a Belkin Wireless G plus MIMO router and have now switched to a Belkin ShareN300 router hooked to a Mediacom modem for internet access. All computers have Internet access but not sure if XP machines are running G versus N standard. How do i find out what class network card is in a laptop and how to upgrade to get best performance from new router?

Comment: Have you already tried looking up the specs on the manufacturers' websites?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to go to control panel->network and check status of each connection. It should tell you the current speed.

Next step, should first somehow fail, would be to go to device managed and see the type of card there. You should be able to find some information based on its name. If you can't, go to properties of the device->details->hardware IDs and search for the ID on the Internet.

Comment: If you're comfortable with PowerShell, you can try [this](http://www.peetersonline.nl/index.php/powershell/gather-nic-properties-including-speed-and-duplex/).